# Website seems to half connect but only sometimes

Tags: ruby, heroku, dns

My problem is that this website does not seem too connect to my custom domain always. When I run host www.domainname.com I get one of two things

```
www.domainname.net is an alias for whispering-orangutan-d7h7k6icnz7lnatv0qdsptdd.herokudns.com.
whispering-orangutan.herokudns.com has address 34.231.75.48
whispering-orangutan.herokudns.com has address 52.2.175.150
whispering-orangutan.herokudns.com has address 54.165.51.142
whispering-orangutan.herokudns.com has address 52.203.53.176
whispering-orangutan.herokudns.com has address 54.164.181.42
whispering-orangutan.herokudns.com has address 34.196.237.103
whispering-orangutan.herokudns.com has address 3.209.102.29
whispering-orangutan.herokudns.com has address 54.173.32.212
```

but then other times I get

```
www.domainname.net has address 23.217.***.***
www.domainname.net has address 23.202.***.***
www.domainname.net is an alias for www235.wixdns.net.
www235.wixdns.net is an alias for balancer.wixdns.net.
```

Comment: How do you handle DNS records? What is your nameserver? How does your configuration look like? When did you change the configuration the last imte?

Comment: @spickermann they are on Wix. I changed everything about 30 min ago. My TTL is 30 minutes though

Comment: Was it 30 minutes too before you changed it? Did you check if the DNS entries were properly propagated – for example with a tool like https://www.whatsmydns.net/ ?